# Why The uploader clear my sessions and logout?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, file-upload

I use the `FileUpload` to upload files.

but i note that :

in the second upload ,the session variables are cleared then log out !!

Why this strange behavior is happened when clicking on `save button` ?and how to fix it ?

---

```
if (fup_logoBannarFile.HasFile)
{
    try
    {
        bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(path + ddl_dep.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()));
        if (!IsExists)
          System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(path + ddl_dep.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()));
          upload_file(fup_logoBannarFile, lbl_successMsg, "LogoBanner");
          load_images();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          errorDiv.Visible = true;
          successDiv.Visible = false;
          lbl_msg.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
     }    
}
```

Comment: Where do you keep the session - In memory or on database ?

Comment: Then probably this is the issue, the session when is on memory is easy lost, ether by pool recycle, ether by need more memory and clear some, ether by reset that memory. Can you add it to database ?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to save your files outside your web site or the iis root directory. 
Because I guess replacing the file in your web site directory may clear the session